# Grails - Cannot get property 'id' on null object

Tags: grails, parameters, parameter-passing

here is i have some problem.

I have 2 domain class and i want to pass some parameter from one to second domain class and save on second.

Here is first domain class Car

```
package carrentco

class Car {

    String brand
    String model
    String fuelType
    BigDecimal pricePerDay

    static constraints = {
        brand(inList:["AUDI", "BMW", "MERCEDES", "NISSAN", "HONDA", "FORD"])
        model()
        fuelType(inList:["FUEL", "DIESEL", "AUTOGAS"])
        pricePerDay(min:0.0, max:1000.0)

    }
}
```

And here is second one Registration

```
package carrentco

class Registration {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    Date dateOfBirth
    String phoneNumber
    String email
    Date startOfRentDate
    Date endOfRentDate
    Car rentedCar

    static constraints = {
        firstName(nullable: false)
        lastName(nullable: false)
        dateOfBirth()
        phoneNumber(phoneNumber: true, nullable: false)
        email(blank:false, email:true)
        startOfRentDate()
        endOfRentDate()
    }
}
```

What i wanna do; I create some cars list and i added to cars/index.gsp some button to each car (RENT CAR) when user click to this button he go to registration/create.gsp here user add some details of himself like name surname etc. I want to get here Car id which one he select from car/index.gsp automatically and save this form. When admin will look to this registration record he will see to Which car user want to rent.

here is my cars/index.gsp

```
 <g:each in="${carList}" var="car">
                <p>${car.id} </p>
                <g:link action="create" controller="registration" params="${[carId : car.id ]}">
                    Rent Car
                </g:link>

            </g:each>
```

and here is my registration/create.gsp

```
<g:form action="save">
    <div><p>Car ID : ${car.id} </p></div>
    <fieldset class="form">
        <f:all bean="registration"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <input type="hidden" name="carId" id="carId" value="${car?.id}"/>
        <input type="text" name="yourName" required>
        <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

when i write this code i get this error,

```
URI
/registration/create
Class
java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/registration/create.gsp:38] Error executing tag <g:form>: Error evaluating expression [car.id] on line [29]: Cannot get property 'id' on null object
Caused by
Cannot get property 'id' on null object
```

When i tried this one in registration/create.gsp

```
 <g:form action="save">
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <f:all bean="registration"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
```

Everything is okey. I can save the registration form with car id, But here i need to select from list which car id. So i don't want this i want this was selected automatically because if i click to rent car button from car list example car id 2 why i need to select in registration form again car id it's not good.

here is my registration controller.

```
package carrentco

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class RegistrationController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond Registration.list(params), model:[registrationCount: Registration.count()]
    }

    def show(Registration registration) {
        respond registration
    }

    def create() {
        respond new Registration(params)
        def selectedCar = Car.get(params.carId)
        [car: selectedCar]
    }

    @Transactional
    def save(Registration registration) {

        if (registration == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return

        }

        if (registration.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond registration.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }

        registration.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'registration.label', default: 'Registration'), registration.id])
                redirect registration
            }
            '*' { respond registration, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    }

    def edit(Registration registration) {
        respond registration
    }

    @Transactional
    def update(Registration registration) {
        if (registration == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (registration.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond registration.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }

        registration.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'registration.label', default: 'Registration'), registration.id])
                redirect registration
            }
            '*'{ respond registration, [status: OK] }
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    def delete(Registration registration) {

        if (registration == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }

        registration.delete flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'registration.label', default: 'Registration'), registration.id])
                redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
        }
    }

    protected void notFound() {
        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'registration.label', default: 'Registration'), params.id])
                redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
        }
    }
}
```

It's my university project so i need help and so much i can't understand what i need to do for solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem obviously comes when "create" action is triggered. Judging by the exception message "car" is not passed to the view. Remove the "respond" statement from the action.

Try this:

```
def create() { 
    [car: Car.get(params.carId)]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the  `${car.id}` as a id of the action `create` in `registeration` controller.  In the cars/index.gsp pass ID also on g:link

```
<g:link action="create" controller="registration" id="${car.id}" params="${[carId : car.id ]}">
```

Now  You have passed value `car.id` as `carId`. It will be available in the Save action. Now you have to associate that car to the registration. Do this in the save action, not in create action.

In registration controller save action:

```
// After checking no errors //
def selectedCar=Car.get(params.carId)
registeration.rentedcar=selectedcar
registration.save flush:true
```

The create action just requires

```
 respond new Registration(params)
```

OR Instead of params in cars/index you can have this in registration/create.gsp

```
<input type="hidden" name="carId" id="carId" value="${params.id}"/>
```